# How to Implement hover selector with javascript to div's

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I have a div container which has 3 sub divs as columns.
There is a background image into the container and i would like when i mouseover on each sub div ,the background of **this** div to change with a specific image.I wish on mouse out the image to be removed and be in the previous status.
i did this with css using hover, but as  i said before it doesn't work in IE9(as custom view within intranet ).The error in console says *SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited.*  but i do not use :visited or :link.

Im new in javascript and i would really appreciate your assistance.
Thank you in advance.
My code is :

```
#container {
width:500px;
height:350px;
border: 1px solid #092D53;  
margin-left:1cm;
margin-top:1cm;
border-radius:5px;
background-image: url('image.png');

}

#column1 {

position: relative;
float: left;
width: 32%;
height: 100%;
border-right: 1px solid #092D53;

}
#column2 {

position: relative;
float: left;
width: 34%;
height: 100%;
border-right: 1px solid #092D53;

}
#column3 {
position: relative;
float:left;
width:32%;
height:100%;

}
#button1 {  
align: middle;
margin-bottom: -45px;
display: table-cell;
position: absolute;
width: 95%;
height: 40px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 40px;
color: #092D53;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 14px;




}
#button2 {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-bottom: -45px;
width:95%;
align:middle;
    text-decoration: none;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 40px;
color: #092D53;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 14px;

}
#button3 {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: -45px;
width: 98%;
height:40px;
align:middle;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: middle;
color: #092D53;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 14px;

}



#column1:hover {    
background-image: url('one.png');
opacity:0.2;
}
#column2:hover {    
background-image: url('two.png');
opacity:0.2;
}

#column3:hover {    
background-image: url('three.png');
opacity:0.2;
}
```

Workflow 1
            
        
        

        
        
            
            Workflow 2
            
        
        

        
        
            
            Workflow 3

Answer (score 0):

jQuery example:

```
$('#column1').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url("one.png")');
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.2');
}, mouseOutHandler);

$('#column2').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url("two.png")');
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.2');
}, mouseOutHandler);

$('#column3').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url("three.png")');
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.2');
}, mouseOutHandler);

function mouseOutHandler() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'inherit');
    $(this).css('opacity', 'inherit');
}
```

jQuery API Documentation of the `.hover()` function:
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

First function of `.hover()` is the mouse enter event function, same as `:hover` would do in CSS. Second function is the mouse leave event function, which puts the applied CSS back to normal.

Comment: Thanks ,seems that works but i have an issue.On mouse out ,the 2nd and the 3rd column change the background as it is on the 1st column.

Comment: Do they have different backgrounds? I can't seem to find that in the CSS you provided.

Comment: The div container only has background image .The sub divs do not have. Thats why i want on mouse out to be in the old status.I hope this helps

Comment: So what do you mean that "the 2nd and the 3rd column change the background as it is on the 1st column."?

Comment: the container has an image ,which is divided by 3 columns.When i hover the 1st column i want the background of the specific div to change with image1 and on mouse out to be in prvious status .The same for the 2nd and the 3rd

Comment: Basically i want on mouseout the picture to be hidden and see again the background image of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#DivID").hover(function(){
   $("#DivID").css("color","yellow");
});
```

Hope it helps.....